# Programmatably Automate Microsoft Outlook Settings

Tags: python, outlook

Is there anyway to set Microsoft Outlook setting, specially the Options-->Mail-->Stationary and Fonts? Our organization has rules set up to set them back to Arial 12 after every restart of the PC which I do often. It only take me 30 seconds to set them back to what I like, but it would be nice if I could use some sort of programming to automate this. Python is my bread and butter language so accessing the API or hacking the settings somehow with it would be best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize the [PyAutoGUI](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouse-keyboard-automation-using-python/) module to control the mouse and keyboard upon computer start up. I've done this before to automate some manual server stuff. You have it start up on computer start up, open the program, Outlook, click Menu, then Options, then Stationary and fonts and have it set it up.

There will be issues with this. Every time Outlook updates things will move around slightly and it won't work. You'll also have to remember to give your computer 60 seconds or so to setup. This isn't an idea solution, but it could do what your asking.

Comment: This actually did work, not the neatest. I am interested if there are any other ideas out there though.